# Drawing on UIView vs UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm new to CG drawing, and I'm confused on where the CG code goes.

What is stopping the idea of putting the draw functions in the UIViewController vs the UIView? How should I determine which parts of the CG code should go where? I see that some of the tutorials have code in viewDidLoad from the view controller, but others say it goes in the view. What determines what goes where?

(Yes this is kind of an MVC question, but Im still having trouble differentiating.)

Answer (score 3):

The correct place for custom drawing code is (almost always) in the `drawRect` method of a subclass of `UIView`.  The usual way to go is to make a custom subclass of UIView and make that the root view of your view controller.  In the view controller's `loadView` method, for example, you can assign `self.view = [[MyCustomView alloc] init];` (autorelease that view if you're in non-ARC code!)  Then your custom drawing code should go in the `drawRect` method of `MyCustomView`.

Answer (score 0):

Core Graphics drawing code can go where ever a valid context is. This means it can go in your own functions if you create your own context.

The reason you generally place Core Graphics drawing code in a UIView subclass is you normally may want to encapsulate the code in a reusable form. But if you were going to create an image from the Core Graphics code you could easily start a new image context, draw, then save the contents of the context into a UIImage. This type of drawing can go anywhere, even a UIViewController. Core Graphics drawing can even be used to generate PDFs. Its simply a simple geometric drawing framework. As long as you have a valid context be it the one created before `drawRect:` is called in a UIView or a context you created on command.